# Text Input on android phone is not in view when the keyboard for webview comes up?

Tags: android, android-webview

I have a webview on an android phone that is a registration form and it contains some fields such as first name, last name, user name, password, etc...  When focus on the first name input field for example, the keyboard pops up, but the input goes out of view, it still has focus though.  Is there a way to keep it in view or is this a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a problem common to Android applications. The application does not scroll the view such that the input field under focus is visible when the soft keyboard appears. There might be a solution, but it is something you'd have to implement and not a bug (per se).

Comment: Same thing happens to me. I usually try to scroll the page while the keyboard is up and if that doesn't work I'll just type. I've just gotten used to it.

Answer (score 1):

I found this answer here :
https://stackoverflow.com/a/5097539/1498996

Add this to your activity tag in the `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<activity android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing"
      //other flags
/>
```

It worked for me.