# Android 2.2 Web View windows moves up when Virtual Keyboard appears

Tags: javascript, android, scroll, cordova

I am developing an Application using Phonegap on Android. Everything works fine on OS 2.1 but on OS 2.2 when we click on any input type text field the keyboard appears and whole window moves to UP side and the input type field becomes invisible. Can anybody tell me what exactly be the problem and can it be solved using javascript? How to stop windows resizing functionality on Android 2.2?

I found the same problem on [Text Input on android phone is not in view when the keyboard for webview comes up?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4305079/text-input-on-android-phone-is-not-in-view-when-the-keyboard-for-webview-comes-up) also, but not the solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I tried to put following css property and it was working for me on Android 2.2

html, body{overflow: hidden;}

Not sure why it is working, but it is working...

Note: I used "iScroll" plugin for scrolling in my application.

Comment: That worked perfectly for me, and I'm not using iScroll. My main app element is centered within the body using -webkit-box.

Answer (score 11):

Adding this

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

to your   in AndroidManifest.xml will solve the issue

Comment: For me adjustPan doesn't scroll input into the view. Android 4.3 Similar issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17483881/webview-does-not-pan-on-android-web-application-with-phonegap

Answer (score 2):

I've never used PhoneGap but I went to their site and I am to understand that it still works via Eclipse and the ADT; if that's the case then this problem can be solved via the `AndroidManifest.xml` file by adding the following to your `<activity>` tag for the activity that is invoking the Soft Keyboard:

```
<activity android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing"
          //other flags
/>
```

**Actually this seems to not be the case.  The API document I was reading was actually for Honeycomb, this flag isn't in 2.2.  Sorry.  All of my work recently has been on tablets and I forgot which version of the SDK I had bookmarked for reading since I've been prepping lately.**

Answer (score 1):

You might have to enable this script to avoid your app scrolling when your text input field gets focus :)

```
function preventBehavior(e) 
{ 
  e.preventDefault(); 
};document.addEventListener("touchmove", preventBehavior, false);
```

Comment: by clicking on textfield, nothing happens, virtual keyboard doesn't appear.

Answer (score 0):

this behaviour on android 2.2 append when there is one element in page with a "transform" css attribute (like transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px); )
removing those declarations fixed the problem for me.
(overflow:hidden also but you can't scroll the app anymore)

PS: overridding the declarations does not work unfortunatly