# Webview does not pan on android web application with Phonegap

Tags: android, web-applications

I'm working on a web application for android and ios by using Phonegap

when the `<input>` element get focus, virtual keyboard pops up, webview panned to top on ios device to avoid keyboard covers input elements, but it does not pan on android.

here is `<meta>` tag in html

`<meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale" name="viewport" />`

and AndroidManifest xml

```
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

i just can't set `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"`

most of html elements's style are using percentage, html page will mess if i use `adjustResize`

is anyone know how to solve this problem? thx

Comment: @RickMortensen unfortunately not

Answer (score 0):

The webview containing my web application has android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" set and I found that when the text input is focused scrolling it into view works great:

```
var elOnFocus = function(e) { 
  var textInput = e.target;

  // Use timeout to allow window to resize
  window.setTimeout(function() {
    textInput.scrollIntoView();
  });
};
```

See: [Element.scrollIntoView()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView)